# When to use CreateChannelWithActAsToken/WithIssuedToken/WithOnBehalfOfToken?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

When transferring security tokens to a WCF service, in which scenario should I use the following similar-sounding methods?

- [`CreateChannelWithActAsToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160113(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`CreateChannelWithIssuedToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194747(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`CreateChannelWithOnBehalfOfToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139510(v=vs.110).aspx)

The documentation does not shed much light on the intended use. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `CreateChannelWithIssuedToken` uses the current process token.
- `CreateChannelWithOnBehalfOfToken` uses an external entity (not the current process). A service would use this to make a call "on behalf" of whomever called the service.
- `CreateChannelWithActAsToken` uses both the current process and the external entity.

From [Window Identity Foundation FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748487.aspx)

> From the WS-Trust procotol standpoint:
>
> - An ActAs RST element indicates
>     that the requestor wants a token that contains claims about two
>     distinct entities: the requestor, and an external entity represented
>     by the token in the ActAs element.
> - An OnBehalfOf RST element indicates that the requestor wants a token
>     that contains claims only about one entity: the external entity
>     represented by the token in the OnBehalfOf element.
>
> The ActAs feature is typically used in scenarios that require
>   composite delegation, where the final recipient of the issued token
>   can inspect the entire delegation chain and see not just the client,
>   but all intermediaries.